# ¿Como refrescar la lista del comboBox en Java?

Tags: java

Utilizo este metodo para llenar el comboBoox respecto a la seleccion de estudiante asi que con este muestro las materias que hacen parte de la carrera del estudiante.

```
 public void listarMaterias(){

 ArrayList <Materia>  lista = pli.getFacuIng().getListaMaterias();



 for (Iterator<Materia> iterator = lista.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Materia next = iterator.next();
        if(carreraPosF.equals(next.getCarrePertenece())){

            comboBoxm1.getItems().add(next.getNombreMateria());
            comboBoxm2.getItems().add(next.getNombreMateria());
            comboBoxm3.getItems().add(next.getNombreMateria());
            comboBoxm4.getItems().add(next.getNombreMateria());
            comboBoxm5.getItems().add(next.getNombreMateria());
            comboBoxm6.getItems().add(next.getNombreMateria());
            // System.out.println("Holaaaaaa"+next.getNombre());
        }
    }

}
```

¿Debo hacer otro metodo o podria aprovechar el mismo para limpiar el comboBox? ya queda siempre quedan guardados respecto a el primer estudiante que selecciono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el método que rellena el `ComboBox`, antes del el bucle `for`, puedes agregar una sentencia que deje vacío el `comboBox`, tal que así:

```
cbx.removeAllItems(); //Remueve todos lo ítems que contenga el combo
```

Así cuando llames, al método `listarMaterias()`, primero removerá todos los datos que están dentro del `ComboBox`, y lo rellenará nuevamente.